# How could I write a css selector that would select 3 elements with only one difference in class name

Tags: css

I have 3 svgs with these class names and would like a selector to select them all.

```
.call-to-action__volunteer-icon, .call-to-action__register-icon, .call-to-action__find-polling-icon
```

There are other elements on the page that use ‘call-to-action__’ as this is part of the BEM method so I cannot just use
svg[class*=“call-to-action”].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain attributes selectors together to make a longer selector, which is what I'd probably do. Something like this:

```
svg[class*="call-to-action"][class$="-icon"]
```

That'd match SVGs with a class name that includes "call-to-action" **and** ends in "-icon".

If need be, you can keep chaining to make a longer and longer selector to get only the ones you want. Say there's some other SVGs on the page with classes like `.call-to-action__unique1-icon` and `.call-to-action__unique2-icon`, which would match the above selector, but you don't want to include SVGs with "unique" as part of their class name.

In that case you can pile a `:not()` onto the end, like this:

```
svg[class*="call-to-action"][class$="-icon"]:not([class*="unique"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
svg.call-to-action__volunteer-icon, svg.call-to-action__register-icon, svg.call-to-action__find-polling-icon, {
  /* enter rules here... */
}
```

Adding multiple rules with a comma seperating them will chain them, applying all the rules inside to them.

Doing `svg.class` selects all svg elements with the class "class".